# How find an specific element of page in Selenium python, because I can't find them

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have tried all ways that I knew, but can't found elements "login" and "password". Could someone help me, please? I am tired...
link: https://trading.finam.ru/

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    import traceback
    from time import sleep
    url = 'https://trading.finam.ru/'
    driver =         webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\Idensas\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\selenium\chromedriver.exe")
    driver.get(url)
    sleep(2)
    try:
        x = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//label[contains(text(),"Логин")]')
        x.send_keys('123')
    except Exception:
        traceback.print_exc()

    finally:
        driver.close()
        driver.quit()
```

[The picture of that site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iM0G.png)

Comment: Welcome! Can you please type your code? So we can see why you couldn't find the elements?

Comment: O, yes, of course.

Comment: See my answer. Your locator is wrong. Additionally you should put much larger delay, 2 seconds is not enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following `xpath`s will work:
`//input[@name='login']`
`//input[@name='password']`

I see the site is loaded slowly so you must put some delay, preferably explicit wait there like:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='login']")))
```

before trying to insert a texts there

Comment: Oh! It's magic! Thank you SO MUCH, I tried only this about ~3 days, and now...Thanks ^^

Comment: UPD: of course, need to append wait = WebDriverWait(driver,40)

Answer (score 2):

Any website takes sometime to completely load and all the elements are visible to user.
To check the time take taken by your website in different regions you run a check on https://gtmetrix.com/

You can use the simple `sleep` for few secs until the page is loaded

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver=webdriver.Chrome(//chromedriver_path_in_your_local//)
driver.get("https://trading.finam.ru/")
time.sleep(5)

login=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='login']")
password=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='password']")
```

Comment: Thanks-thanks! Now I am not so tired, because my task is complete, have a good day)

Comment: Al the best. Have a nice day!